# keep :ex open and try to escape <CR>

Tags: linux, vim

1. Would like  **map f :help**  in .vimrc to execute :help in ex and wait for me to press enter key.
2. If I try to **set laststatus=2**  in my .vimrc in current working directory I get **Error detected while processing E521: Number required after =: laststatus=2^M**

Comment: Formatting is poor, wording is imprecise. Put more effort in your question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't want `map`, but `noremap`, a non-recursive map.

   ```
   noremap f :help
   ```
2. Are you copy-pasting that command? You seem to be pasting the carriage-return in there too and Vim thinks your number is `2^M`. Try to type it all instead:

   ```
   set laststatus=2
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Adding command separator **|** at the end of **map f :help |** solves the problem 1.